# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException (Uni work)

Tags: java

```
import easyIO.*;

class Oblig3A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    OrdAnalyse oA = new OrdAnalyse(args[0]);
    oA.textLeser();
    } //closes main
} //closes Oblig3 class

class OrdAnalyse {

    String[] ord = new String[5000];
    int[] antall = new int[5000];
    int antUnik = 0;
    String argu;


    OrdAnalyse(String file){

    argu = file;
    } //args relay

    void textLeser(){
        In lesText = new In(argu);
    Out nyText = new Out("oppsummering.txt" , true);

    while (!lesText.endOfFile()) {
        String reader = lesText.inWord();
        for(int i=0; i<ord.length; i++) {

        if(reader.equals(ord[i])) {
            antall[i]++;
            antUnik++;
            ord[i] = reader;
            nyText.out(ord[i]);
        } //if

        else {
            antall[i]++;

        } //else
        } //for
    }//while
    }//textLeser
}//OrdAnalyse.class
```

Anyone able to spot the thing thats wrong? :S need help.

I have no idea what's wrong with it, I've tried lots of different things. :/

Not sure why that is though :s

line 33 =  if(reader.equals(ord[i])) {

Comment: Show us the stack trace.

Comment: Where dos the exception occurs? you should have a line number and tell us where that line is.

Comment: " I've tried lots of different things." Even debugger? :)

Comment: [tomrm@starrenburg ~]$ java Oblig3 Alice.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
[tomrm@starrenburg ~]$ 


This is the whole error message.

Comment: Where is the nullpointer exception? Which line?

Comment: You're running `Oblig3` there, not `Oblig3A`, is that your intention?

Comment: Doesn't tell me the line :/

Comment: yeah Oblig3 and Oblig3A are the same so shouldn't be a problem

Comment: just tried it with a different file and got this 



Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at OrdAnalyse.textLeser(Oblig3A.java:33)
 at Oblig3A.main(Oblig3A.java:8)

Comment: Now tell us which is line 33. We don't want to count (plus line 33 in your code is not necessarily line 33 in what you pasted).

Comment: @EtienneMiret Line 33 in this snippet is `if(reader.equals(ord[i]))`

Comment: @EtienneMiret Fixed my last comment.

Comment: line 33 edited in btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> just tried it with a different file and got this
>
> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at OrdAnalyse.textLeser(Oblig3A.java:33)
>     at Oblig3A.main(Oblig3A.java:8)
> ```

Based on your comment, the following method invocation returns `null`.

```
String reader = lesText.inWord();
```

Later on, at line 33, you access the `reader` variable.

```
if(reader.equals(ord[i]))
```

Invoking a method on a null object throws the `NullPointerException` you've seen.

Most probably, `inWord()` in conjunction with `endOfFile()` isn't working as you expect. You need to read the documentation for both methods, and then decide how to handle `null` results from `inWord()`: The easiest solution is to break the outer loop, but you might want to do something else.

```
String reader = lesText.inWord();
if (reader == null) { break; }
```

Comment: Edited to add line 33

Comment: @MrAdonexus Edited answer for further clarification.

Comment: changed line 33 to:  if(reader == ord[i]) { seems to have gotten rid of the error

Comment: @MrAdonexus It does get rid of the error, but it won't do what you expect. For instance, try `(new String("a")).equals("a")` and `(new String("a")) == "a"`, and you'll see diffent results.

Comment: yeah, noticed it just spammed my document with null...

Changed it back and realised i had forgotten a '!' infront of it, so i'm still getting errors anyways

Comment: @MrAdonexus As suggested in my answer, for some reason `inWord()` is returning a null word. Perhaps the file does not contain a word to read, although the end of file hasn't been reached. Only seeing the code can I give you a certain answer. For now, all I can tell you to do, is to check if `reader` is null *before* calling `equals` on it, and then decide what to do when it is `null`.

Comment: Ok, got it working with your break, but it now pastes the word in like, 5000 times each <.< fml just made a 668mb file with just text

Comment: @MrAdonexus That's because of the `for(int i=0; i<ord.length; i++)`. You see, `ord.length` is 5000, so the code inside this for (which includes writing to the file) will be repeated 5000 times. Since the matter to this question seems to be solved, consider accepting one of the answers, and open a new question if you encounter further issues.